# Found https://magento-analytics.com/5cd060d51e45d.js script in HTML head and footer script in admin

Tags: magento2

We are facing one weird problem.

Suddenly we found `https://magento-analytics.com/5cd060d51e45d.js` script in HTML head and footer script in admin theme.

This script breaks the searching functionality of store.

Anyone have any idea about this script ?? Please let us know.

Comment: looks like malware

Comment: I'd have all your admin users update their passwords and then take a dive into the admin actions log and see when/where the head and footer scripts were updated. The IP addresses should also be available for each action log.

Comment: This is a credit card stealer malware!

Comment: @user80224 how to prevent from this malware ?

Comment: This is a Card Skimmer. See here for details https://blog.netlab.360.com/ongoing-credit-card-data-leak/

Comment: how to prevent from this malware ?

Comment: my best advice is to change admin password immediately, try to know how the hacker was able to place the malicious JS in your server as well. Most compromise servers has been because of weak credentials

Comment: @n00b11 Thank you so much for this information. Can we contact to https://blog.netlab.360.com ?? Do you have any contact details of them ?

Comment: That's probably not useful unless you want to become a paying customer of theirs. See instead https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Answer (score 2):

This is malware that steals creditcard info.

https://thehackernews.com/2019/05/magento-credit-card-hacking.html

Answer (score 1):

Some solace: you are not alone. This malware is currently injected on 284 stores, according to last night's scan.

You should run a thorough scan of your server to find any backdoors they may have planted. See my opensource scanner @ https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner or a commercial version @ https://sansec.io.

You should also conduct a root cause analysis, otherwise you will likely have the same problem again in two weeks (20% of merchants get reinfected after the first time, see https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2018/11/12/merchants-struggle-with-magecart-reinfections/)

In general, you should search for requests containing "adminer", "phpmyadmin", "cms/block", "theme/design_config/save", and find other requests from the same IP addresses.